# Verilog - shift register queue or circular queue?

Tags: queue, verilog

I've got 2 ways to implement a queue in verilog.

1. Shift register way - As you dequeue, you shift all the values forward. At the same time keeping a queue counter to keep track of number of items and also facilitate your enqueue to the back.
2. Circular queue way - Keeps 2 pointer/counter to point to the head and end of the queue. When you dequeue, increment the head pointer; when you enqueue, increment the end pointer. Loops back to 0 when you reach the end of the array. Might want to keep a queue counter to keep track the number of items or use the 2 pointers to find out.

For the question, which is a better way?
If I want to enqueue and dequeue in the same clock cycle, does one work better than the other?

I think for the circular queue, it would be much more straight forward where you just add it to wherever the end pointer is pointing. While the shift register queue might have to check where to insert at each shift.

Then again, both's enqueue are base on pointer to do the insertion. So the wire mapping for both will be equally complex? (Just some thoughts while typing the question)

Thanks.

Comment: For the point of flexibility and program complexity, i think circular queue is better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, Circular queue is better.

**Advantages :**

- You don't need to shift any data.
- You just need to update the pointers.
- Counter update is also required in Shift Queue, same like Circular Queue.
- You do not require to shift data, in order to fetch the data, so read & write latency improves
- No need of extra bit to check, whether a location contains data or not.